# How to modify multiple element nodes and text nodes in javascript and which of code is more clear to use?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have question about this two similar codes , and want to know advantages and disadvantages of using it.or there is no matter which one use?In first version I am using parameters  and in second not...
Also interested in `` all_h1.querySelectorAll(`h1`) ``
Why is not same as `const children =parent.childNodes;`

````
```HTML 
 <div id="parent">
      <h1>We Will Manipulate LIVE nodeList Element nodes and #textNodes</h1>
      <h1>We Will Manipulate LIVE nodeList Element nodes and #textNodes</h1>
      <h1>We Will Manipulate LIVE nodeList Element nodes and #textNodes</h1>
      <h1>We Will Manipulate LIVE nodeList Element nodes and #textNodes</h1>
      <h1>We Will Manipulate LIVE nodeList Element nodes and #textNodes</h1>
      <h1>We Will Manipulate LIVE nodeList Element nodes and #textNodes</h1>
    </div>
```
````

```
  .addStyle {
    width: 1050px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    padding: 0.5em 0.5em;
  }
```

first version of the code with using Parameters:

```
const parent = document.querySelector(`#parent`);
//const children = parent.childNodes; 

const function_CreateH1 = (parent_container, text_parameter) => {
  parent_container.insertAdjacentHTML(`afterbegin`, `<h1>${text_parameter}</h1>`);
};


function_CreateH1(parent, `Add New H1 element Wait (1,2,3...and Go)`);

const replaceAllH1Text = (all_h1, newtext_parameter) => {
  all_h1.querySelectorAll(`h1`).forEach((elem) => {
    elem.textContent = newtext_parameter;
    elem.style.backgroundColor = `brown`;
    elem.style.color = `white`;
    elem.classList.add(`addStyle`);
    //Why isn't working children.forEach and etc.

  });
};

setTimeout(() => {
  replaceAllH1Text(parent, `We access and Modify H1 elements itselfs and #Text nodes`);
}, 3000);
```

Second version of the code without using Parameters in function:

```
const parent = document.querySelector(`#parent`);
//const children = parent.childNodes;

const function_CreateH1 = () => {
  parent.insertAdjacentHTML(`afterbegin`, `<h1>Add New H1 element Wait (1,2,3...and Go)</h1>`);
};

function_CreateH1();

const replaceAllH1Text = () => {
  parent.querySelectorAll(`h1`).forEach((elem) => {
    elem.textContent = `We access and Modify H1 elements itselfs and #Text nodes`;
    elem.style.backgroundColor = `brown`;
    elem.style.color = `white`;
    elem.classList.add(`addStyle`);
    //Why isn't working children.forEach and etc.
  });
};

setTimeout(() => {
  replaceAllH1Text();
}, 3000);
```

Comment: Once you've created your list items why not just iterate over `document.querySelectorAll('li');` and update the `textContent` of each item.

Comment: @Andy using forEach yes?...

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the code looping `document.querySelectorAll`.

For the creation of a new `li`-element the snippet contains a separate function `appendLi`. It uses [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) and a [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to append the new `li`.

The function `replaceAllLiText` contains the loop to change the text for all `li`'s in the `ul`.

```js
const appendLi = (ul, text) =>
  ul.insertAdjacentHTML(`beforeend`, `<li>${text}</li>`);
  //                    │             ^┍ the html to append, 
  //                    │              │ using a template string
  //                    │              ┕ to inject [text]
  //                    ┕ add the html last within [ul]
const replaceAllLiText = (ul, nwText) => 
  ul.querySelectorAll(`li`).forEach(li => li.textContent = nwText);
  //                        │                ┕ set [li] text to [nwText]
  //                        ┕ loop all li's within [ul]
const ul = document.querySelector(`ul`);

// append a new li-element with text to the ul
appendLi(ul, `this is new Li (wait a sec...)`);

// wait two seconds, then change the text of all li's 
setTimeout(() => replaceAllLiText(ul, `This is working`), 2000);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>foo</li>
  <li>bar</li>
  <li>bar</li>
</ul>`
```

Comment: it's look nice,thank you .But for me looks like complicated.I am just beginner.. I will look more deeply to your code and learn about ```insertAdjacentHTML()``` method .

Comment: I've added some (hopefully clarifying) comment in the snippet code.